# How do I authenticate my server based app with Zoho SDK?

Tags: c#, authentication, zoho

I hope this makes sense.  I am using the Zoho C# SDK examples to write records to the CRM Leads.  While calling recordOperations.CreateRecords(); it fails after trying to GetToken from the Token Store.
Here is the token I am saving

```
Token token = new OAuthToken(
      "xxxx.clientid.goes.here.xxxxx",
      "xxxx.clientsecret.goes.here.xxxx",
      "REFRESH/GRANT token",
      TokenType.GRANT,
      string.Empty);
 TokenStore tokenStore = new CustomTokenStore();
 tokenStore.SaveToken(user, token);
```

And I am sending this token into the SDKInitilizer.Initialize.  No errors at this point.  Next I try and create a lead.  When it gets inside of recordOperations.CreateRecords(); it tries GetToken and I've hard coded it to return exactly what was in the token object above.   CreateRecords throws an error for "invalid_code".    Here is what is in the log file

```
21-09-07 16:49:34 [INFO]: Initialization successful for Email Id : myemail@email.com in Environment : https://www.zohoapis.com.
21-09-07 16:49:47 [INFO]: Access Token has expired. Hence refreshing.
21-09-07 16:49:50 [ERROR]: Exception in authenticating current request : {"Code":"INVALID CLIENT ERROR","Message":"invalid_code","Cause":null,"Details":null,"StackTrace":"   at Com.Zoho.API.Authenticator.OAuthToken.ParseResponse(String response)\r\n   at Com.Zoho.API.Authenticator.OAuthToken.RefreshAccessToken(UserSignature user, TokenStore store)\r\n   at Com.Zoho.API.Authenticator.OAuthToken.Authenticate(APIHTTPConnector urlConnection)\r\n   at Com.Zoho.Crm.API.Util.CommonAPIHandler.APICall[T](Type className, String encodeType)","Data":{},"InnerException":null,"HelpLink":null,"Source":"ZCRMSDK","HResult":-2146233088}
```

It appears to be failing when it tries to refresh the token so I assume I am not sending in the right info in the token object?

*** Edit for @sucasa ***
This is what I am sending into the Initialize method.
[image]

What I have figured out since my first post is, I'm not getting the initial `token` from Initialize and its not calling the custom `TokenStore.SaveToken()` I created and it should, right?  If I save it, all I have is what is above, not an actual `token`.  So I think when I go to create the lead, I don't actually have the initial token to refresh.  I hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access Tokens expire and must be refreshed using a refresh token. The error message indicates this. Can you log the value of `token` and report back here?

Comment: I added more information in the description.

Comment: You seem to be missing a few steps. the first step outlined in this doc https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/csharp-sdk/initialize.html should be performed in Postman. Get an access token and refresh token before you even begin to start writing any c# code. You can replace ‘self client’ with ‘server client’. Also the redirect URL is important, you set that in the developer console and you need to provide it in further steps even if its localhost

Comment: I get it now.  I generated the Refresh token in the API Console, and when I create the token object, the third parameter is "token" and I send in the refresh token id and I change the TokenType to "REFRESH" and now it works.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Nice! Beware that there is a rate limit on generating the access token. Instead of generating one with each request you can do that once every 45 min then use that token. Do this in cases where you may be calling a service in large bursts such as in response to large record imports